# Distributed Algorithm to get an ordered list of nodes in a bipartite graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, distributed-systems, parallel-computing, performance

Given a weighted bipartite graph with nodes of type A and B, I want to output an (approximately) ordered list of type B nodes as defined by the following heuristic:

1. For each node of type B, sum over all the edge weights for edges to node B.
2. Select the node from type B which has the highest value and append it to the output set S.
3. Delete the selected node from type B and all the nodes it had an edge to from type A.
4. Go back to step 1 until any node in type B is left with no edge to a node in type A.
5. Append any remaining node of type B to the output set in any random order.

The figure below shows an example (both in graph as well as matrix format):

[image]

For this example the output set will be : (C,A,B,D) or (C,A,D,B).

The naive process will be a simple walkthrough the algorithm. But assume that type A nodes are in the magnitude of ~1B and type B nodes are in the magnitude of ~10-20MM - I am looking for the most efficient (or distributed?) algorithm to find the output set. Note that an approximation of the output set also works.

The approach I have right now from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62338424/given-a-bipartite-graph-with-node-weight-get-ordered-list-of-one-type-of-node-ba) is to basically maintain a max-heap with the overall solution being O((m+n) log m).

Comment: I don't understand what kind of answer you are expecting or what the question is.  You described an algorithm you want to use.  I'm not sure what more is left for us to say, as  the only option is to use the algorithm you already specified.

Comment: @D.W. 'as the only option is to use the algorithm you already specified' - maybe that answers it. I am looking for a parallel (approximation) of the sequential algorithm or something that could be more efficient to get to the same answer if there is any. For example, (i) maybe we can take a weighted one-mode projection of the bipartite graph and then apply some heuristic on that, that leads to the same expected output OR (ii) maybe we can perform an initial clustering step on the bipartite graph and send each cluster to a computing node independently and then merge the results ...

Comment: 1. Does step 4 have a typo?  Do you mean "is left with no edge"?  I am not clear on the termination condition of the loop.  Can you [edit] the question to make that clearer?  2. I always get suspicious when I see someone define a problem by the specific method that must be used to solve it, rather than a spec of the input and the desired output.  It seems like confusing the goal with the method of achieving it.  This makes me wonder whether you might be able to articulate what problem your algorithm is indeed to solve.  Are you trying to solve an instance of the assignment problem?

Comment: 1.You are right, corrected the typo, thanks.

Comment: 2. I understand what you are saying - I am okay with any method as long as we achieve the goal (input - weighted bi-partite graph, output - an array of type B nodes).  I haven't heard about the assignment problem - I will read up on that.

Comment: @D.W. I will try to give an intuition - assume type A nodes are water sources and type B nodes are water taps. Then the edge weight represents some notion of volume of water flowing through the pipe (edge). The problem is to find an order of opening the taps to maximize the volume of water collected. The catch is that as soon as you open a tap eg tap C (in our example above in step 1), "all" the water from source Y and Z starts flowing through tap C - thats why in step 2 we now remove those water sources (Y & Z), to decide which tap to open next that will give the maximum flow of water.

Comment: The problem is that the goal is not well-specified in a way that is independent of the method.  You say you want the output to be an array of type B nodes, but presumably if I just picked a random collection of type B nodes in a random order, you would not be happy -- so you must have some additional goal or requirement or evaluation metric.  Perhaps you can identify some objective function that you want to maximize.  Perhaps you can identify some hard requirements on the output that can be formalized.  It's the difference between how you achieve something vs what you want to achieve.